# Conversion of Datetime and CHAR in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

I am working with performance tuning in our sqlserver application. We have some dependencies against an old application that has a database which is not good.

I have no authority to change that database. We can do select from that database and nothing more.

My problem is that they have created two columns for date.

The first column is a `DATETIME`.
The second column is a `CHAR(5)` that has the form `hh:mm` which is the time.

Stupid thing to do but I cannot change that.

When I perform an `SELECT` statement that like:

```
SELECT (startdate + starttime) as StartDateTime
FROM t1
```

an implicitly conversion is performed by sqlserver.
As I understand sql server does not use indexes when an implicitly conversion is performed.

I need to know how write an SQL that does not perform an implicitly conversion!

BR

Big Spender

Comment: You can't. You are turning two strings into a datetime. The only way you could avoid the implicit conversion would be to perform an explicit conversion. But that is not going to make any difference from a performance perspective. You are stuck with sub-par performance because of a sub-par design.

Comment: Also, indexes are used to identify rows to be returned from a query. The example you posted has no where clause so no amount of indexing is going to help there. It is pulling all the rows from the table.

Comment: Can you clarify what you need? Why would that query use an index? If your asking about a WHERE clause and startdate is indexed you would query for startdate and starttime independently, restricting by the date then the time.

Comment: It is not exactly true that "SQL Server does not use indexes when an implicit conversion is performed". It *is* true that most expressions defeat the ability of the optimizer to use an index seek, but you're not seeking, you're calculating a result. Even in suboptimal cases like those, you can still leverage indexes by doing coarse filtering, then finer filtering (possibly on complicated expressions): `WHERE StartDate >= ... AND StartDate < ... AND StartTime >= ... AND StartTime < ...` can get you much better results than trying to squeeze it all in one expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast both to datetime

```
SELECT (CAST(startdate AS DATETIME) + CAST(starttime AS DATETIME)) as StartDateTime FROM t1
```

EXAMPLE

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (startdate DATE, starttime CHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES 
('2018-04-18','15:05')

--Cast both to datetime 
SELECT (CAST(startdate AS DATETIME) + CAST(starttime AS DATETIME)) as StartDateTime 
FROM @TBL
```

OUTPUT

```
    StartDateTime

   2018-04-18 15:05:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to convert the values into the ISO datetime format (`yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss`) and then convert it to a `datetime`. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), [date],102),'.','-') + 'T' + [time] + ':00.000')
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'20180418') AS [date], '15:02' AS [time]) As T1
```

Of course, in the `WHERE` this'll perform awfully. Thus, you might want to create in indexed view with that column in it.